# Merge 2 rows with duplicated pair of values into a single row

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below in which there are 2 rows with the same pair of values for columns `A` and `B` -3RD AND 4RTH with 2 3 -, -7TH AND 8TH with 4 6-.

```
master <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), B=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8),C=c(5,2,5,7,7,5,7,9,7,8),D=c(1,2,5,3,7,5,9,6,7,0))



A B C D
1  1 1 5 1
2  1 2 2 2
3  2 3 5 5
4  2 3 7 3
5  3 4 7 7
6  3 5 5 5
7  4 6 7 9
8  4 6 9 6
9  5 7 7 7
10 5 8 8 0
```

I would like to merge these rows into one by adding the pipe | operator between values of `C` and `D`. The 2nd and 3rd line for example would be like:

```
A B C  D
2 3 2|5 2|5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your combined pairs are off by a row in your example, assuming that's the case, this is what you're looking for. We group by the columns we want to collapse the duplicates out of, and then use `summarize_all` with `paste0` to combine the values with a separator.

```
library(tidyverse)

master %>% group_by(A,B) %>% summarize_all(funs(paste0(., collapse="|")))

      A     B C     D    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1     1 5     1    
2     1     2 2     2    
3     2     3 5|7   5|3  
4     3     4 7     7    
5     3     5 5     5    
6     4     6 7|9   9|6  
7     5     7 7     7    
8     5     8 8     0
```

Comment: great and simple

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ A + B, master, FUN = paste, collapse= '|')
#  A B   C   D
#1 1 1   5   1
#2 1 2   2   2
#3 2 3 5|7 5|3
#4 3 4   7   7
#5 3 5   5   5
#6 4 6 7|9 9|6
#7 5 7   7   7
#8 5 8   8   0
```